# How to install azure-cli on RHEL 7.9

Tags: azure, rpm, azure-cli, rhel7

I'm trying hard to install *azure-cli 2.50* or at least version *2.49*. On my RHEL 7 VM, however, it installs 2.38 version.

Microsoft has said that they will not deliver further packages post 2.38 for RHEL 7 but will provide updates to 2.38.

I tried the following commands:

- `sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc`
- `sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/azure-cli.repo`

```
[azure-cli]
name=Azure CLI
baseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
```

- `sudo yum update azure-cli`
- `az --version`

OUTPUT:

[image: azure-cli version snapshot]

I need at 2.49 version on RHEL 7.9

If any one could help me with tweaks to install 2.49 version, that would be great. Don't know if it's even possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear answer to this. It can require hours or even weeks of work.

RHEL 7 will be EOLed in a few months. And if MS refused to provide updates (and they likely have a reason), I would not even try it. And instead, migrate to RHEL 9 (or 8). You will have to do that soon anyway.